# PHP Regex matching

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a string in PHP and it's doing my head in.
The string I have is:

```
http:\/\/xxx.xxx\/xxx
```

I want to replace the

```
\/
```

with just

```
/
```

(to give http://xxx.xxx/xxx). All the escapes and stuff are confusing the hell out of me, though!

I've tried every combination I can think of. I thought:

```
$str= preg_replace("\ \\ \/ /", "/ \/ /", $str);
```

would do the trick (removing the spaces) but no luck.

Can someone quickly help me out here? I'm about to lose the will to live.

Thanks!

Comment: `stripslashes` suffices. Is the string residing in JSON by any chance? --Also, super shallow question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex add complexity, use a simple [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace('\/', '/', $str);
```

### Test

```
$str="http:\/\/xxx.xxx\/xxx";
$str= str_replace("\/", "/", $str);
echo $str;
```

Output

> http://xxx.xxx/xxx

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a regex, you can just use str_replace :

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

This task can be done with [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Regular expression is used whenever it is useful not everywhere.

```
 $str= str_replace("\\", "", $str);
```

### Test

```
$str="http:\/\/xxx.xxx\/xxx";
$str= str_replace("\\", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Output

> http://xxx.xxx/xxx

## **Edit**

If you want to remove the back-slashes, you can also use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
$str="http:\/\/xxx.xxx\/xxx";
$str= stripslashes($str);
echo $str
```

## *Live Demo*

Comment: you don't *have* to, but yes, `str_replace` is a better option

Comment: I did, and wrongly edited your answer (my bad), I was aiming to add a 'Test' section in my answer. Your pattern is incorrect, check again the input string

Comment: @EdouardLopez Both are perfect answer see here http://codepad.org/dhZk4V8S and here http://codepad.org/pm0z6djN . So no need to downvote correct answers.

Comment: @EdouardLopez to escape the first slash.

Comment: @EdouardLopez http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php It's pretty common knowledge so I don't think it needs a special mention.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I upvoted you back, could you add this to your answer

Comment: i didn't downvote, but i still don't like this answer because it implies you MUST use `str_replace`, when that's not true. you could use `preg_replace` or other options if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace()` requires the first character to be your delimiter, also the backslash needs to be double escaped, once for the string, and once for the regex):

`$str = preg_replace('#\\\\/#', '/', $str)`

But as other users have suggested, it might be simpler to just use str_replace:

`$str = str_replace('\/', '/', $str);`

Answer (score -2):

this is a source of regex, I suggest you to check it . http://overapi.com/regex/

Comment: While I appreciate the time you've taken to try and help me, this wasn't helpful at all.